# LINQ not reading parenthesis

Tags: c#, sql, linq, entity-framework

This is my LINQ (EF):

```
var ls = from ps in ctx.Package_Services
     where 
        (ps.Package.Policy.Name != "Short-Term Career Policy"
            && ps.Package.Name != "Early Talent Package")
        &&
        (ps.Package.Policy.Name != "Assignment Policy"
            && ps.Package.Name != "Efficient Package")
     select new
     {
         Service = ps.Service,
         PackageService = ps
     };
```

This is the relevant SQL that it generates:

```
WHERE (N'Early Talent Package' <> [Extent2].[Name]) 
AND (N'Efficient Package' <> [Extent2].[Name]) 
AND (N'Short-Term Career Policy' <> [Extent3].[Name]) 
AND (N'Assignment Policy' <> [Extent4].[Name])
```

What I'm trying to say is, "I don't want combination X and I also don't want combination Y; however, I do want "Early Talent Package" where they are not tied to "Short-Term Career Policy." And, I also want "Efficient Package" when they are not tied to "Assignment Policy."

How can I translate that into LINQ?

Comment: if you remove the parenthesis the logic is still the same.  Try changing the `&&` outside the parenthesis to `||` and I would expect it would keep them

Comment: If I change the `&&` to an `||` it includes everything as if I had no `where` at all.

Comment: Are you changing only the outer `&&` to `||`, or all of them?  If all of them, then its' not correct.

Comment: @MikeC Just the outer one.

Comment: @GrantWinney Damn, you're right.  Well, how can I make it do what I want?  I explained it in words in my last paragraph of the question. Just not sure how to translate it into LINQ.

Comment: @user1477388 I think that I outline a better translation of your stated logic to a resulting where clause.

Comment: Try to formulate your question in a less technical way.  Are you saying "I have a collection of apples, bananas and strawberries. A fruit is "acceptable" if it is an apple, but yellow apples are not acceptable. Or a fruit is acceptable if it is a banana, but not if it is a green banana. No strawberries are acceptable.  Then what you want is `(isApple && !isYellow) || (isBanana && !isGreen)`.

Comment: @EricLippert I have a feeling he's just going to wait this one out until he's allowed to accept his own answer to the question.

Answer (score 5):

It probably eliminates them because it doesn't need them.

You're effectively saying "not this" *and* "not this" *and* "not this" *and* "not this".

Now if you had an "OR" in the middle, it'd have to take them into account:

```
(ps.Package.Policy.Name != "Short-Term Career Policy"
    && ps.Package.Name != "Early Talent Package")
||
(ps.Package.Policy.Name != "Assignment Policy"
    && ps.Package.Name != "Efficient Package")
```

Comment: When I change the `and` to an `or` it behaves no differently than if I included no `where` statement at all.

Answer (score 2):

Based on what you say you're trying to achieve:

> I don't want combination X and I also don't want combination Y;
>   however, I do want "Early Talent Package" where they are not tied to
>   "Short-Term Career Policy." And, I also want "Efficient Package" when
>   they are not tied to "Assignment Policy.

I think your boolean logic is just flawed in general.

You want **Early Talent Package** when it is not tied to **Short-Term Career Policy**:

```
((ps.Package.Policy.Name == "Early Talent Package") 
 && (ps.Package.Policy.Name != "Short-Term Career Policy"))
```

OR (`||`)

You want **Efficient Package** when not tied to **Assignment Policy**:

```
((ps.Package.Name == "Efficient Package") 
 && (ps.Package.Policy.Name != "Assignment Policy"))
```

All together:

```
((ps.Package.Policy.Name == "Early Talent Package") 
    && (ps.Package.Policy.Name != "Short-Term Career Policy"))
||
((ps.Package.Name == "Efficient Package") 
    && (ps.Package.Policy.Name != "Assignment Policy"))
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer; however, it doesn't appear to work.  It only returns 8 records. My answer below is what has worked for me.

Comment: Without seeing your data and / or results, it's hard to to tell if it's because it's not returning the data you expect, or if you're expecting different results than you actually laid out.  I don't see how my example is filtering out too much unless you're also looking for records where the `Package.Name` is not `Early Talent Package` OR `Efficient Package`

Comment: @user1477388 I did realize that I wasn't using extra grouping parenthesis which may have caused an issue in your results, so I've added them.

Answer (score 0):

This is what worked for me.

```
var ls = from ps in ctx.Package_Services
         where 
            !(
                (ps.Package.Policy.Name == "Short-Term Career Policy"
                    && ps.Package.Name == "Early Talent Package")
                ||
                (ps.Package.Policy.Name == "Assignment Policy"
                    && ps.Package.Name == "Efficient Package")
            )
         select new
         {
             Service = ps.Service,
             PackageService = ps
         };
```

The SQL it generates is like so:

```
SELECT 
1 AS [C1], 
[Extent4].[Id] AS [Id], 
[Extent4].[Name] AS [Name], 
[Filter1].[Id1] AS [Id1], 
[Filter1].[PackageId] AS [PackageId], 
[Filter1].[ServiceId] AS [ServiceId], 
[Filter1].[SectionId] AS [SectionId], 
[Filter1].[Mandatory] AS [Mandatory]
FROM   (SELECT [Extent1].[Id] AS [Id1], [Extent1].[PackageId] AS [PackageId], [Extent1].[ServiceId] AS [ServiceId], [Extent1].[SectionId] AS [SectionId], [Extent1].[Mandatory] AS [Mandatory]
    FROM   [dbo].[Package_Services] AS [Extent1]
    INNER JOIN [dbo].[Packages] AS [Extent2] ON [Extent1].[PackageId] = [Extent2].[Id]
    INNER JOIN [dbo].[Policy] AS [Extent3] ON [Extent2].[PolicyId] = [Extent3].[Id]
    WHERE ( NOT (((N'Short-Term Career Policy' = [Extent3].[Name]) AND (N'Early Talent Package' = [Extent2].[Name])) OR ((N'Assignment Policy' = [Extent3].[Name]) AND (N'Efficient Package' = [Extent2].[Name])))) AND (N'Exception Policy' <> [Extent3].[Name]) ) AS [Filter1]
INNER JOIN [dbo].[Services] AS [Extent4] ON [Filter1].[ServiceId] = [Extent4].[Id]
WHERE N'Transportation' = [Extent4].[Name]
```

Comment: but thats logically different to the question. `(!A & !B) & (!C & !D)` does not commute to `!((A & B) | (C & D))`

Comment: @Jodrell: The source of the discrepancy lies with the original poster, whose code does not match their description of it.

Comment: @EricLippert the OP is the answerer here.

Comment: @GrantWinney I have added the generated SQL.

Comment: @Jodrell This exactly computes to `!((A & B) | (C & D))` which is what I was trying to describe - not X or Y, but can be parts of both.

Comment: @EricLippert I think my description matches exactly what my code does which is "not X or Y, but can be parts of both."

Comment: @user1477388: Right. Jodrell is saying that your new code doesn't match your original code. I'm pointing out that your new code doesn't match the original code because **you asked the question because the original code was wrong**. If the new code did match the old code then it would be *equally wrong*.

Comment: @EricLippert Exactly right, my original code was wrong so I was asking for a better solution.  Fortunately, I found it.